# Building a REST service with C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest

How can i build a REST service with C#.net?

Is there any articles I can check?

Google results return C# REST client but I d like to build one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build this with WCF.

Check out the resources on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) for lots of information on the subject. Especially [A Developer's Guide to the WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Use one of the REST frameworks for .NET.

See for example [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta).

Comment: I haven't looked at OpenRasta, but what are the advantages over WCF?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best article series I have read on REST is here: http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/?tag=/restful&page=2

Answer (score 0):

[WCF REST PROGRAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) EDUCATION CONTENT ON MSDN Library.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you Nancy Framework, inspired by Sinatra (for Ruby): http://nancyfx.org/